# How can the following inequality hold for any real $x$?

Tags: inequality

$|1-x| + |1 + x| \ge 2$?

I've tried proving this as:

$|1-x| + |1+ x| \ge 1 - |x| + 1 - |x| = 2 - 2|x|$, and here, of course, I can't say $2- 2|x| \ge 2.$

Edit: Thanks so much, everyone.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can write $2 = (1+x) + (1-x)$ and use triangular inequality.

Answer (score 1):

$2 = |(1-x) + (1+x)|  \leq  |1-x| + |1+x|$ by triangle inequality.

Answer (score 0):

First look at it more intuitively: $|1-x|$ is the distance between $x$ and $1$, and $|1+x|=|x-(-1)|$ is the distance between $x$ and $-1$. If $-1\le x\le 1$, the sum of these distances is $2$; if $x<-1$ or $x>1$, the sum of these distances is more than $2$.

Now use the cases suggested by that, i.e., $x<-1$, $-1\le x\le 1$, and $x>1$, to verify the general inequality.

Answer (score 0):

If $x\geq1$:
$$
|1-x|+|1+x|=x-1+1-x=2x\geq2.
$$
If $-1\leq x<1$:
$$
|1-x|+|1+x|=1-x+1+x=2.
$$
If $x<-1$:
$$
|1-x|+|1+x|=1-x-1-x=-2x\geq2.
$$

Answer (score 0):

If you note that the expression on the left hand side is the same as
$$|x-1| + |x-(-1)|$$
and you interpret this as the sum of the distances  from $x$ to $\pm 1$, then this is obvious, isn't it?

Just think about the three cases of the location of $x$ on the number line.
If $x$ is to the right of $1$ or to the left of $-1$, then it's at least $2$ units from one or the other; and if it's between them, the sum of the distances is the distance from $-1$ to $1$.

Answer (score 0):

Note that this is clearly true when $ |x|\geq 1$. So you only have to worry about $-1 <x <1$. But then $1-x$ and $1+x$ are both positive, so you can eliminate the absolute values.

Answer (score 0):

**HINT**: Use Triangle inequality - $$|a|+|b| \ge |a+b|$$

Answer (score 0):

Here's a complicated, but kind of fun, way to show the inequality, using the general properties of the absolute value, $u\le|u|$, $|u|^2=u^2$, and $|u||v|=|uv|$.

Noting that both sides of $2\le|1-x|+|1+x|$ are non-negative, we have

$$\begin{align}
2\le|1-x|+|1+x|&\iff4\le(|1-x|+|1+x|)^2\\
&\iff4\le(1-x)^2+2|(1-x)(1+x)|+(1+x)^2\\
&\iff4\le2+2x^2+2|1-x^2|\\
&\iff2-2x^2\le2|1-x^2|\\
&\iff1-x^2\le|1-x^2|
\end{align}$$

Since the last inequality is an instance of the general property $u\le|u|$, the original inequality hold.

Comment: @basic, glad you like it.  Note, this is in essence a proof of the triangle inequality itself:  $|a+b|\le|a|+|b|\iff(a+b)^2\le(|a|+|b|)^2\iff a^2+2ab+b^2\le a^2+2|ab|+b^2\iff$ etc.